# Changing a variable in Forloop

Tags: java, for-loop, bar-chart

i have to make a chart on luggage Statistics.
The code below will show 4 bars per month, in a bar-chart.
i have a sidebar(not given here) were i can fill in the range of details i want (Example, 1 January till 20 August).

now i thought of something like a for loop, wich sets a line depening on the amount of months.
in the example above this will be te following code

```
dataset.addValue(getMissing(), series1, Month1);
dataset.addValue(getMissing(), series1, Month2);
dataset.addValue(getMissing(), series1, Month3);
dataset.addValue(getMissing(), series1, Month4);
dataset.addValue(getMissing(), series1, Month5);
dataset.addValue(getMissing(), series1, Month6);
dataset.addValue(getMissing(), series1, Month7);
dataset.addValue(getMissing(), series1, Month8);
```

how do i make a loop which adds the codeline, AND increase the Month

Kind regards

```
    // row keys...
    String series1 = "Luggage Lost";
    String series2 = "Customer Missing";
    String series3 = "Recovered";
    String series4 = "Forever Lost";


    // column keys...
    String Month1 = "January";
    String Month2 = "February";
    String Month3 = "March";
    String Month4 = "April";
    String Month5 = "May";
    String Month6 = "June";
    String Month7 = "July";
    String Month8 = "August";
    String Month9 = "September";
    String Month10 = "October";
    String Month11 = "November";
    String Month12 = "December";

    // create the dataset...
    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();


    for (int aantalmaanden = 0; aantalmaanden==0; aantalmaanden--) {


    }

    dataset.addValue(getMissing(), series1, Month1);
    dataset.addValue(getMissing(), series1, Month2);
    dataset.addValue(getMissing(), series1, Month3);
    dataset.addValue(getMissing(), series1, Month4);
    dataset.addValue(getMissing(), series1, Month5);

    dataset.addValue(getFound(), series2, Month1);
    dataset.addValue(getFound(), series2, Month2);
    dataset.addValue(getFound(), series2, Month3);
    dataset.addValue(getFound(), series2, Month4);
    dataset.addValue(getFound(), series2, Month5);

    dataset.addValue(getHandel(), series3, Month1);
    dataset.addValue(getHandel(), series3, Month2);
    dataset.addValue(getHandel(), series3, Month3);
    dataset.addValue(getHandel(), series3, Month4);
    dataset.addValue(getHandel(), series3, Month5);

    dataset.addValue(getForeverlost(), series4, Month1);
    dataset.addValue(getForeverlost(), series4, Month2);
    dataset.addValue(getForeverlost(), series4, Month3);
    dataset.addValue(getForeverlost(), series4, Month4);
    dataset.addValue(getForeverlost(), series4, Month5);

    return dataset;

}
```

Comment: can't you keep Months in an array instead of saying Month1, Month2, etc.. Then you can loop that array.

Comment: Use an `Enum` for Months and iterate over its values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use arrays:

```
String[] serieses = {
    "Luggage Lost",
    "Customer Missing",
    "Recovered",
    "Forever Lost"
};

// column keys...
String[] months = {
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
};
```

Then either boring `for` loops:

```
int seriesNum;
int monthNum;

for (seriesNum = 0; seriesNum < serieses.length; ++seriesNum) {
    for (monthNum = 0; monthNum < months.length; ++monthNum) {
        // Do something with serieses[seriesNum] and months[monthNum] here
    }
}
```

...or enhanced `for` loops:

```
for (series : serieses) {
    for (month : months) {
        // Do something with series (a String) and month (a String) here
    }
}
```

Comment: To initialise the array with month names I would use Java power  ;-)
`String[] months = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.forLanguageTag("NL")).getMonths();` which can be internationalised.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to change the variable in the loop, but the value of the variable:

```
    for (String month: new String[]{"January","February","March"...}) {
        dataset.addValue(getMissing(), series1, Month3);            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`String month[] = new String[12]`  you have to create array of months

// add months in array

```
for(int i=0;i<moth.lenth;i++){
dataset.addValue(getMissing(), series1, month[i]);
}
```

If you want to iterate over month and series then you have to use `nested for loop`

```
String series[] = new String[4];
```

// add series in array

```
for(int i=0;i<series.lenght;i++){

 for(int j=0;j<month.lenght;j++){
   dataset.addValue(getMissing(), series[i], month[j]);
 }
}
```